# Stem and Leaf Plot for Strongly Skewed Data

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, descriptive-statistics

How to draw a stem and leaf plot for the following large data, the data is for different EU states so there is a large difference between the data. I have to plot stem and leaf for each table i.e. area, population as well as size of motorway. How do I arrange it in stem and leaf,How many stems would be there (let's say for motorway length) do I have to split the data. Do I have to round or truncate the data?

I have arranged the length of motorway in ascending order;

0, 0, 11, 140, 152, 257, 309, 392, 419, 541, 644, 751, 770, 810, 897, 1295, 1340, 1419, 1482, 1515, 1719, 1763, 1891, 2005, 2127, 2631, 2988, 3686, 6726 11465, 12917, 14701

[image]

Comment: I have edited your title. The term 'big data' is generally used for datasets with many thousands of observations. Here you have only 32.

Comment: Thank you Bruce for correction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not guess that a stemplot is the best way to visualize these
data, and so I would not recommend one way of setting up the stems
as better than another. Particularly so, because the data are strongly skewed to the right, spanning
a couple of orders of magnitude.

Nevertheless, stem plots can be made: Here is the default stemplot of these 32
observations from R, followed by the one from Minitab, in which
the line beginning `(8)` has eight observations, one of which
is the median 1318.

```
   R
   The decimal point is 3 digit(s) to the right of the |

    0 | 00012334456888933455789
    2 | 01607
    4 | 
    6 | 7
    8 | 
   10 | 5
   12 | 9
   14 | 7



 Minitab:
 Stem-and-leaf of Motorway  N  = 32
 Leaf Unit = 100

  15  0   000112334567788
 (8)  1   23445778
  9   2   0169
  5   3   6
  4   4
  4   5
  4   6   7
  3   7
  3   8
  3   9
  3   10
  3   11  4
  2   12  9
  1   13
  1   14  7
```

With the parameter `scale=.5` the R function `stem` returns the
abbreviated stemplot below.

```
   The decimal point is 4 digit(s) to the right of the |

   0 | 0000000001111111111222222334
   0 | 7
   1 | 13
   1 | 5
```

I do not see how to make a stemplot on any scale without losing
some of the detail of the data. If information is to be lost
in making a graphical presentation of the data, perhaps a histogram is a better choice. Below is a Minitab histogram of
these data.

[image]

For some purposes, it might be better to make a histogram of $\log_{10}$ of motorway lengths for the 30 EU states that have
motorways.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bruce for explanation, I am required to draw it by hand :( , I spent sometime to get the idea of mini-tab. Can I visualize it using Scatter Diagram or Cumulative frequency and box plot

Comment: I hope you have figured out that a stemplot should indicate the location of the decimal point. I don't believe that a first column (with cumulative counts) as in Minitab is expected in a stemplot made by hand. The original idea of a stemplot was as a quick way to visualize data in a pre-computer age, and some people feel it is not necessary to sort the 'leaves' in increasing order in a hand-drawn stemplot. Maybe your assignment gives some guidance on that.

Comment: Yes Professor, Thank you for your assistance. Yes, the location of decimal point required a lot of effort, I worked it out. The assignment requirements does not specify the order but I have arranged it in order as it is easy to work out